# How do I get John the Ripper running on a recent version of debian or ubuntu?

Tags: debian, password, john-the-ripper

Although John the Ripper has been packaged for debian and ubuntu, it seems that as of August 2015 the packaged version doesn't actually work. Recent versions of these systems encrypt passwords using the sha512 hash function, but support for that hash function is only currently available through a user-supported version of the program. The symptom of this problem is the generic error message "No password hashes loaded." How do you get it to work?

Comment: Debian feature request for the jumbo version: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=806977

Answer (score 11):

Go to http://www.openwall.com/john/ and find the URL of the latest community-enhanced version, which is in xz format.

```
wget http://www.openwall.com/john/j/john-1.8.0-jumbo-1.tar.xz
tar xf john-1.8.0-jumbo-1.tar.xz
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
cd john-1.8.0-jumbo-1/src && ./configure && make
cd ../run
sudo ./unshadow /etc/passwd /etc/shadow > ~bcrowell/mypasswd.txt
./john mypasswd.txt
rm mypasswd.txt
```

Comment: +1 useful info though this gave me a compilation error. I just went with `apt-get install john` instead for a trouble free install in case anyone else runs into this problem